# Change the default Application Insights log level in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, azure, appinsights

By default, Azure's Application Insights only [captures events at the INFO level and above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#autocollected-logging). I want to change the default level to INFO in a Spring Boot app. I tried to achieve this by adding the following configuration section in `application.yml`

```yaml
azure: 
  application-insights:
    enabled: true
    connection-string: 'my-secret-connection-string'
    logger:
      level: DEBUG

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    com.myapp: DEBUG
    com.microsoft.azure.telemetry: DEBUG
```

But it doesn't seem to have worked. How can I change the default logging level for Application Insights?

I'm using Spring Boot v3.2.2 with applicationinsights-web v3.4.19

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change the default logging level for Application Insights?

The configuration you provided seems correct, but it might not be taking effect.

- It is not recognizing this configuration properly. Instead, you should configure the logging level using Spring Boot's logging configuration properties.

**`application.yml`** file:

```yaml
azure:
  application-insights:
    instrumentation-key: YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY

logging:
  level:
    com.microsoft.azure.telemetry: INFO
```

***Replace `INFO` with the desired logging level (e.g., `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `WARN`, `ERROR`).***

& also check whether you're specifying the correct logger name for Application Insights. The logger name for Application Insights might vary based on the Azure SDK version or logging framework being used.

[image]

**Dependencies** used in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
 <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>  
 <version>3.4.18</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
 <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>  
 <version>3.4.18</version>  
</dependency>
```

**App insights:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my question to show my new configuration and the specific dependencies I'm using. I'm still not getting any debug logging in Azure. Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out that the Spring configuration has no impact on the Application Insights log level. The correct place to configure this is in an `applicationinsights.json` file that looks like this

```json
{
  "role": {
    "name": "MyApp"
  },
  "sampling": {
    "percentage": 100
  },
  "instrumentation": {
    "logging": {
      "level": "DEBUG"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, You need to update `applicationinsights.json` in this scenario

Refer to the below snippet for `JSON` example

[image]

For detailed help kindly follow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config